# Remove locale from the system

Tags: server, 9.10, locale, internationalization

For some obscure reason, my `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` file contained an extra locale that typically should not be there (in my example, `pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8`).

I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`, and the system reported:

```
Generating locales...
  el_GR.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

that is, it verified that the rest of the locales are up-to-date; however, there was no mention of the `pl_PL.UTF-8` locale. I don't know if it erased files related to the locale.

How can I make sure that there are no files left in the system for the pl_PL.UTF-8 locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `localepurge`? (`aptitude show localepurge`)

Comment: This probably did the job. I'll select your answer as *the* answer after the next successful reboot :)

Comment: Try bleechbit, it can free much more than localepurge.

Comment: @Extender: AFAIR bleechbit is a tool to free space from *user* data.